# Error EPSG:4326 on Geonetwork 2.1.3

Tags: geoserver, srs, epsg, geonetwork

I have an error with geoserver 2.1.3 when I try to view a map in OpenLayers.

I have added in the Limited SRS list the codes `4326`, `900913`, `3857` and I add a code for `900913` in the `espg.properties` because at first i have an error with that. But now I have these error with the EPSG:4326. I have looked at all the places and solutions, but none worked for me.

```
ERROR [geoserver.ows] - org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG%3A4326
 at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:181)
 at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:74)
 at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1230)
 at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:488)
 at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:231)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:23)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
 at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
 at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
 at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.georchestra.security.ProxyProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(ProxyProcessingFilter.java:82)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:71)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:41)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No se ha especificado ninguna autoridad para el código "EPSG%3A4326". El formato esperado es normalmente "AUTORITÉ:NOMBRE".
 at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.noSuchAuthority(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:488)
 at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:466)
 at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:547)
 at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:799)
 at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:730)
 at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:179)
 at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:488)
 at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:416)
 at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:176) ... 72 more DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: application/vnd.ogc.se_xml;charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this bit in your error log:

> org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No se ha
>   especificado ninguna autoridad para el código "EPSG%3A4326". El
>   formato esperado es normalmente "AUTORITÉ:NOMBRE". at

I assume you should try not encoding the authority and just putting "EPSG:4326". Also, you might wanna reformat your answer so the log doesn't appear in just one line :-)

Comment: Thx for the reply Mike, i diden't see that was only one code there, well i am trying to see a map in format EPSG:4326 but dont show when i try to use OpenLayers
PS. i dont know why i cant show the log in code line

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that, somewhere, you've defined "EPSG:4326" and later encoded it as a URL parameter when, it seems, geoserver cannot understand an encoded authority (it reads "EPSG%3a4326" instead), so you might want to be sure that when the request is made to geoserver, the EPSG string is UNencoded.

Comment: Thanks for the kick response, well i've the code is:
t.eq(layer.tile.url, "http: //www.bsc-eoc.org/cgi-bin/bsc_ows.asp?typename=OWLS&maxfeatures=10&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-187.890625,-36.6796875,-12.109375,156.6796875", "Tile URL is set correctly when not encoded");
I dont know how to change this or edit becuase its in several places the same code with a few variations

Comment: Is that string hardcoded or is it built using parameters you've defined before? If it's the first case, I'd try changing it manually and if not, just check what parameters it uses and changing that.

Comment: I use maven to get the .war files, and it's coded like that, well i will try to change in the coded already generated in the tomcat directory and i will let you know how it works :)